# Is it possible to publish multiple APKs of different apps to Google Play using Fastlane?

Tags: android, google-play, fastlane, google-play-developer-api

I have multiple apps on Google Play and I would like to publish all APKs using some kind of script, to avoid publishing manually one by one.

I've read about fastlane, but I couldn't find anything in the documentation saying it's possible to publish several apps at the same time.

Is this possible using fastlane or any other tool?

Answer (score 1):

it should be possible using *supply* from fastlane

e.g: Fastfile

```
lane :deploy_all do
   deploy_single_apk(apk: "file1.apk", package_name: "my.app.package2")
   deploy_single_apk(apk: "file2.apk", package_name: "my.app.package2")
end


lane :deploy_single_apk do | options |
  supply(apk: options[:apk],
         package_name: options[:package_name],
         key: "google_play_key.json"
         skip_upload_metadata:true,
         skip_upload_images: true, 
         skip_upload_screenshots:true
  )
end
```

calling it with `fastlane deploy_all` would upload 2 apks to 2 apps on play.

however if you also wan't to update screenshots/metadata/images - you'd need a bit more work to do, as it requires a `metdata` folder per app.

let me know if this helps you.